# Docker daemon already running but still got: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-daemon

I am trying to use vscode on the containers running on a remote server, but when I use 'Attach visual studio code' function I got this:
[image]

I have docker daemon running:
[image]

[image]
I am in the 'docker' group and I am able to run docker without sudo:

[image]

I am running out of solutions here could someone help me?

@Romain
This is the print out of `ps aux | grep -i vscode` (I just screenshot the process of my userid):
[image]
System Info:
Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS;
vscode version:
Version: 1.60.0-insider (Universal)
Commit: 699084fdb48460c68086b85b5c08f3d39055e772;
vscode Docker extension version:
v1.15.0

Comment: Have you tried to run the command VSCode is running `docker version --format='{{.Server.APIVersion}}'`? Could you please check if VSCode is running with your user?

Comment: Hey Romain, I just asked my Admin to add me as a sudoer and it fixed the problem... Maybe it is because VSCode was not running with my user ? How to check that?

Comment: @Romain well it worked for a while... after I close the vscode and restart it, the error occurs again ...

Comment: To check the user that is running VSCode you can do `ps aux | grep -i vscode`.

Comment: @Romain, I edited the post to include a screenshot of this command

Answer (score 1):

I am struggling with this problem too with Docker Desktop for Mac Intel Chipset.

The error is because docker.sock location for Docker Desktop default is `/Users/<user>/.docker/run/docker.sock` and some third party use  `/var/run/docker.sock` as default.

You can make sure by manually creating symlink using this command:

`sudo ln -s -f /Users/<user>/.docker/run/docker.sock /var/run/docker.sock`

You can automatically create symlink from Docker Desktop setting.
`Allow the default Docker socket to be used (requires password)`

[image]

More information about the docker socket in this link

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/permission-requirements/

Answer (score 0):

Update the 'remote-container' extension of vscode to latest on your remote host and local host.